# Difference in elapsed time of the query where everything in the trace seems to be identical

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

While analysing the traces of the program , one before and one which I have run after creating two new indexes, I found some queries which are now having high runtime compared to previous run(which are not using any of the new indexes i have created and have identical execution plans).

One particular query is :

```
SELECT GP.PERIOD_YEAR, GP.PERIOD_NAME, GP.PERIOD_YEAR || '-' || 
LPAD(GP.PERIOD_NUM, 2, '0') 
FROM
GL_PERIODS GP WHERE GP.PERIOD_TYPE = :B3 AND GP.PERIOD_SET_NAME = :B2 AND 
GP.ADJUSTMENT_PERIOD_FLAG = 'N' AND TRUNC (:B1 ) BETWEEN TRUNC 
(GP.START_DATE) AND TRUNC (GP.END_DATE)

Before Stats:
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute 1738112     31.63      31.26          0          0          0           0
Fetch   1738112    778.18     780.36         17    6952448          0     1738112
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total   3476225    809.81     811.63         17    6952448          0     1738112

After Stats:
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute 1738112     75.80      76.87          0          0          0           0
Fetch   1738112   1490.70    1499.47         17    6952448          0     1738112
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total   3476225   1566.50    1576.36         17    6952448          0     1738112
```

And wait events for this query are

1. db file sequential read,
2. latch: cache buffers chains,
3. latch: shared pool

which are not having total wait time of more than a second.

So what I want to know is why this particular query is showing such difference in runtime? What all areas should I look into to get the cause of runtime difference.

I have run the programs in the same instance. Let me know if some more information is required.

Comment: creating index not always help for reducing query execution time.

Comment: @eatSleepCode That is totally fine. But I want to know what may be the possible reasons of the increase in runtime where the buffer counts are identical.

Answer (score 0):

As per oracle documentation on performance tuning:

You can use indexes to boost the performance of queries that return less than 15% of the rows in a table. A query that returns 15% or more of the rows in a table is executed faster by a full scan, that is, by reading all rows sequentially.

So in your case please check number of rows fetched are not greater than or equal to 15%.

You can refer this [performance tuning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apc.htm) documentation.

Comment: @eSC: I have not touched this query at all. The indexes I have created is on different tables.